# How to i can disable some button in "edittext" keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to disable some buttons into the soft keyboard.

For example, I want to disable the `0` button then my `edittext` is empty.

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3){

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

}

});
```

Comment: You need to add more context to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, sorry. After all, the input method editor may not have "keys" in the first place.

> Specifically I want user can't input a ( , ) character when virtual keyboard is showed up when user focus on a standard android EditText widget.

Then you will have to block the input at the `EditText`, by means of an `InputFilter`, as is described here:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```